# Why is the key not being found in the hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I print out the key being searched for and the keys in the map and they are there but the assignment fails. I test by populating the map with one object and itterate through and print out the keys. The key I am referencing is there so I can't see how temp is null?

```
    Birds temp = (Birds)hint.get(input.substring(0, input.length()-1).trim());//the last char is being dropped off on purpose
    if(temp == null)
    {
        System.out.println("failed to map key");
        Iterator entries = hint.entrySet().iterator();
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry thisEntry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
            System.out.println("Key1: "+ 
                thisEntry.getKey()); //this an next line printout the same
            System.out.println("key2: "+
                input.substring(0, input.length()-1).trim());
        }
    }
```

I added the following lines to bird class but still the same problem

```
@Override public int hashCode()
    {
        return name.hashCode();
    }

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Bird b = (Bird)obj;
    String str = b.name;
    if(str.compareTo(this.name) == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Turned out white space was screwing things up and I wasn't calling `trim()` often enough.

Comment: Did you define your .hashCode() and .equals() method for Birds?

Comment: The keys seem to be strings, and .hashCode() and .equals() don't matter for the values.

Comment: @JustinKSU Nope!! What are those? I followed [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/hashmap_get.htm).

Answer (score 7):

When you call [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29), keep in mind that the ending index is not included in the substring.

> The substring begins at the specified `beginIndex` and extends to the character at index `endIndex - 1`

In your call

```
input.substring(0, input.length()-1)
```

you are actually taking the last character off of whatever is currently in `input`.  So, if you had a key `"finch"`, you are inadvertently looking up the key `"finc"`.

I don't see a reason for the `substring` call at all; remove it:

```
Birds temp = (Birds) hint.get(input.trim());
```

Additionally, the cast to `Birds` would be unnecessary if you supplied generic type parameters to your `HashMap`, something like this:

```
Map<String, Birds> hint = new HashMap<>();
```

Then, when calling get, you no longer need the cast:

```
Birds temp = hint.get(input.trim());
```